# Training validation and accuracy are very high, but testing accuracy is low

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

The training accuracy and validation accuracy of my model is extremely high.

```
...
Epoch 4/5
457/457 [==============================] - 4s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0237 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.0036 - val_accuracy: 0.9993
Epoch 5/5
457/457 [==============================] - 4s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0166 - accuracy: 0.9941 - val_loss: 0.0028 - val_accuracy: 0.9994
```

However, upon testing, the accuracy is atrocious:

[image: normalized confusion matrix]

(for high accuracy there would be a green diagonal from top-left to bottom-right)

I am not sure why this is, given the high accuracy and low loss of both the training and validation set. If the model was overfitting, then either the validation loss or accuracy should be deviating from the training loss or accuracy, but it is not.
Here are my data generators:

```py
train_datagen = DataGenerator(
    partition["train"], 
    labels, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    **params
)
val_datagen = DataGenerator(
    partition["val"],
    labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    **params
)
test_datagen = DataGenerator(
    partition["test"],
    labels,
    batch_size=1,
    **params
)
```

Note that since my data takes the form of a npy array on a .npy file, I followed [this post](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to create a custom datagenerator class.

Here is my training process:

```
history = model.fit(
    train_datagen,
    epochs = 5,
    steps_per_epoch = len(train_datagen),
    validation_data = val_datagen,
    validation_steps = len(val_datagen),
    shuffle = False,
    callbacks = callback,
    use_multiprocessing = True,
    workers = 4
)
```

Here you can see how I partitioned my data:

```py
print(len(partition["train"]))
print(len(partition["val"]))
print(len(partition["test"]))
print(len(partition["train"]) + len(partition["val"]) + len(partition["test"]))
print(good, ok, bad)
# good: 0, ok: 1, bad: 2
```

```
29249
8342
4144
41735
18152 12665 10918
```

I also confirmed that there is no overlap between any of the sets:

```py
print(bool(set(partition["train"]) & set(partition["val"])))
print(bool(set(partition["test"]) & set(partition["val"])))
print(bool(set(partition["train"]) & set(partition["test"])))
```

```
False
False
False
```

Can someone please help me figure out where I went wrong? I'm not sure how it's possible to get such high testing and validation accuracy, but have a terrible testing rate. I have hosted everything on [Github](https://github.com/4a454646/StridedTransformer-Pose3D).